# ¿Por qué "tomar el pelo" a alguien significa engañarlo o burlarse de él?

Tags: etimología, modismos, expresiones

Con frecuencia oímos frases del tipo:

> - ¿Sabes qué? Hoy le dije a mi jefe que no quiero trabajar más horas
>   extras.
>
> - Anda ya, **no me tomes el pelo**: tú eres incapaz de decir algo así.

Es decir, con "tomar el pelo" nos referimos a burlarse de alguien, o incluso engañarlo.

Busco su origen y no encuentro nada concluyente: [unos opinan](https://sigificadoyorigen.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/tomar-el-pelo/) que viene de la costumbre de cortar el pelo a los reclusos, [otros también mencionan](http://www.aulafacil.com/articulos/sabias/t2077/el-origen-de-la-expresion-tomar-el-pelo) la opción de que tocar la barba era un gesto ofensivo.

Sin embargo, parece que no hay quorum al respeto. ¿Alguien tiene fuentes fiables sobre su origen? Además: ¿se usa en todos los países?

Comment: En Colombia si se usa, pero se usa más su sinónimo ["mamar gallo"](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mamar_gallo). **Tomar el pelo** es frase de señora refinada, **mamar gallo** es del resto del pueblo  :)
Esto daría para otra pregunta para cuando tenga tiempo: Cuál es el origen "mamar gallo". ?

Answer (score 2):

Tomado de [esta respuesta a otra pregunta parecida](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/22021/13628):

En [AulaFacil](http://www.aulafacil.com/articulos/sabias/t2077/el-origen-de-la-expresion-tomar-el-pelo) proponen dos posibles teorías, yo me quedo con la primera:

> La importancia de las barbas según la época y cultura que analicemos, y lo ofensivo que podía llegar a resultar que alguien tocase o tirase de ella sin consentimiento de su dueño; un acto que podía llevar inmediatamente a una pelea o duelo entre el “agresor” y el “agredido”.

En la respuesta de AlexBcn arriba enlazada se pueden encontrar detalles sobre el origen de la importancia de la barba.