# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "dar para el pelo"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

Según la RAE:

> [**dar** a alguien **para el pelo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SPSNBuG#7U9kIMe)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Darle una tunda o azotaina. U. m. c. amenaza.

Es decir, se usa principalmente para amenazar a alguien con darle una paliza. Se incluyó en el DLE en la edición de 1970, aunque se pueden encontrar casos en el CORDE desde principios del siglo XX. Pero ¿qué tiene que ver una paliza con el pelo? Existe otra expresión que es la siguiente:

> [**caérsele** a alguien **el pelo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SPSNBuG#7Tpo7sx)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Recibir una reprimenda, castigo o sanción si se descubre que ha hecho algo mal.

Entiendo que en este caso el pelo se te cae del disgusto por recibir el castigo. ¿Tienen alguna relación las dos frases? ¿Se entiende "dar para el pelo" como una versión sarcástica de "te voy a dar una que se te va a caer el pelo"?

Comment: Lo único que he encontrado son dos expresiones similares con el mismo significado que a lo mejor pueden ayudar a buscar por otros caminos: *dar para castañas* y *dar para peras*.

Comment: Buscando en el CORDE *dar pa el pelo* aparecen dos más antiguos de  Perez Galdós de 1873 y de 1888.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acabo de hacer un descubrimiento buenísimo que igual hasta puede dar motivo al origen de esta expresión. Veréis, las primeras expresiones que he encontrado son en el CORDE la siguiente:

> 1873: "...porque yo soy muy reseñorona y muy requete-usía, y sé dar pa el pelo, y vivan los farolones de Madrid."

y en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España la siguiente:

> 1888: "El *San Antonio* naufragó en la costa marroquí, cuyos naturales, después de quemar el barco, quisieron dar para el pelo á los marinos."

Pues bien, por aquella época, mediados del siglo XIX, en los periódicos era muy habitual leer anuncios de productos contra la calvicie, basados en el aceite de bellotas, al que se le atribuían buenísimas propiedades. Aquellos anuncios tenían [esta pinta](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0000423850&page=4&lang=es):

[image: Anuncio para el pelo]

Como se ve, parece el típico producto milagro que lo mismo te cura la calvicie que te quita las migrañas. Este anuncio concreto ocupaba una parte importante de la sección de anuncios, y debió ser bastante famoso, porque en julio de 1872 recibió [la siguiente parodia](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003706546&page=4&lang=es) en un semanario de carácter humorístico llamado El Garbanzo, editado en Madrid y que, por favor, os recomiendo encarecidamente que leáis y que la comparéis con el anuncio real:

[image: Parodia para el pelo]

No debe ser una coincidencia que no haya ningún caso de la expresión "dar para el pelo" antes de esta fecha. Seguramente sea una expresión creada a partir de esta parodia, o incluso a partir del anuncio del producto específico para el pelo, sabiendo ya la gente que en realidad servía para bien poco. Pero me inclino a pensar que a partir de esta parodia se creara la expresión "darle a alguien para el pelo" para indicar que, al igual que le pasó a la suegra, le vas a dar algo "para el pelo" que al final lo dejará en el cementerio. Sabemos ya por [otras preguntas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/19748/12637) que el Madrid de la época era un caldo de cultivo para la generación de este tipo de frases jocosas a la mínima de cambio.

Comment: Muy bueno. Tu teoría cuadra bastante bien y sea o no cierta (será difícil de confirmar) la parodia de la loción mágica es impagable.

Comment: Hilarante que hasta parodian el nombre del inventor de tal remedio mágico. Genial respuesta. Coincido en que este es uno de esos casos en los que difícilmente va a haber un origen documentado como tal, y que probablemente fuese una expresión nacida un poco "de casualidad" y adoptada en el habla coloquial casi sin darse cuenta.

Answer (score 1):

No hay fuente válida alguna, pero en varios sitios la expresión similar de "tomar el pelo" se define como:

En [AulaFacil](http://www.aulafacil.com/articulos/sabias/t2077/el-origen-de-la-expresion-tomar-el-pelo) proponen dos posibles teorías:

> La importancia de las barbas según la época y cultura que analicemos, y lo ofensivo que podía llegar a resultar que alguien tocase o tirase de ella sin consentimiento de su dueño; un acto que podía llevar inmediatamente a una pelea o duelo entre el “agresor” y el “agredido”.

o:

> Teoría basada en corte de pelo que se les hacía a los presos y a los militares de nuevo cuño como medida higiénica en cárceles y cuarteles, y que se consideraba una burla hacia éstos.*

De allí llegué a El Cid.

[Mio Cid y sus Barbas](http://slideflix.net/doc/307272/m%C3%ADo-cid-y-sus-barbas):

En el poema se deja crecer su barba por lealtad al Rey Alonso y meso la de algún otro:

> "Essora el Campeador-prísos(e) a la barba; No sólo se deja crecer la
>   barba, sino que quiere que se haga famosa. ¿Qué avedes com de-por
>   retraerla mi barba? p or esso es luenga(dice)-que a delicio fo criada.
>   Y le debió crecer muy rápidam ente, ya que le im presionó hasta al
>   rey. Ca no me priso a el la -fijo de m ugier nada "... catándol(e)
>   sedie la barba-que ta n aínal(e) creció. com o yo a vos, com de-en el
>   castiello de Cabra. nim bla m essó-fijo de m oro ni de cristiana, Q
>   uando pris a Cabra-e a vos por la barba Maravíllanse de mío
>   Cid-cuantos que y(allí) son". non í (allí) ovo rapaz-que non messó su
>   p u lg a d a ".

[*Mesar* (DLE)](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=mesar)

> Arrancar el cabello o la barba con las manos, o tirar con fuerza de ellos.

[Poema del Mio Cid (Los mejores clásicos)](https://books.google.nl/books?id=3wQyCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&lpg=PT41&dq=Poema%20del%20Mio%20Cid%20(Los%20mejores%20cl%C3%A1sicos)#v=onepage&q=mesar%20la&f=false):

> El mesar la barba era un acto injuriante que algunos fueros castigaban con la misma pena que la castracion.

[Libromancia](http://libromancia.blogspot.nl/2010/01/el-tejido-simbolico-en-el-cid.html):

> Si desde que iniciamos viaje con lo humano y heroico marcado por la mesura, la valentía y atributos como la religiosidad, también veremos en esa larga barba muy cuidada, el símbolo de virilidad, poder y hora. Analizaremos cómo recurrentemente se hace mención a la barba, cómo El Cid se deja crecer la barba como símbolo de honor y cómo el asir la barba del enemigo resulta una falta gravísima.

Por último una escultura en Burgos:

[image: http://pm1.narvii.com/6464/3d4ce8ef80ecbeb50f1b496efa5284bd68c0d526_hq.jpg]

No sé si su origen es a partir del *Cantar de mio Cid*, pero su importancia es notable en la obra. Así pues varias expresiones en alusión al pelo podrían significar burlar, amenazar o hasta recibir una pena.

En nuestra defensa podríamos decir *¡¡No me toques ni un pelo!!*

Comment: Hay una [pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16734/por-qu%c3%a9-tomar-el-pelo-a-alguien-significa-enga%c3%b1arlo-o-burlarse-de-%c3%a9l/16743#16743) que trata sobre la expresión *tomar el pelo*, tal vez podrías mover allí tu respuesta.

Comment: Exacto, sería interesante mover esta respuesta a [¿Por qué “tomar el pelo” a alguien significa engañarlo o burlarse de él?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16734/1674). Si eso ofrezco una recompensa allí :)