# ¿Tiene una connotación negativa la frase «tomar el pelo»?

Tags: modismos

En inglés hay una expresión similar: «to pull someone's leg». Pero esta expresíon se usa mayormente para situaciones de broma. O sea, el engaño es solo para reirse, no para engañar con motivos de lucro u otro motivo serio.

¿Es igual para la expresíon español «tomar el pelo»? ¿O puede ser absolutamente sinómino con «engañar», por cualquier motivo que sea?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Por qué “tomar el pelo” a alguien significa engañarlo o burlarse de él?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16734/1674)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Tomar el pelo” no significa realmente “engañar”, sino “burlarse con mentiras”. Si a uno le toman el pelo, significa que fue engañado, pero lo principal es que fue engañado de manera ruin, burlona, humillante.

En forma de pregunta, “¿Me estás tomando el pelo?” puede ser equivalente al inglés, “Are you pulling my leg?” o también “Are you kidding me?”. Pero el tono siempre es hostil, negativo. Para comprobar si un amigo nos está jugando una broma hay otras preguntas: “¿Es broma?”, “¿Lo dices en serio?”, etc. (hay muchas alternativas dependiendo del dialecto).

Si alguien te estafa (te engaña por dinero), eso no es una tomada de pelo. “Tomar el pelo” puede incluir mentiras muy importantes, pero no se aplica a robos, estafas o trampas similares. Es sólo para engaños que dejan en ridículo al otro.